# Windows Server 2003 in vmware wont go online

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware

my host machine is a 64bit Windows 7 Enterprise device.  I have vmware player installed and have a virtual machine running XP SP3 for some old fashioned vb6 development.  Inside this virtual OS, I can access the internet fine. Virtual Machine Network Adapter is set to NAT.

I also have another virtual machine, running Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2.  This is also set to NAT.  However, I cannot access the web from inside this machine.  Troubleshooting attempted include turning off firewalls, setting the vmware network connections on my host machine to auto retrieve IP & DNS and a long search on google.  I found this, http://www.techexams.net/forums/off-topic/27651-vmware-nat-not-working-correctly.html but can't seem to follow the instructions as it's obviously a much older vmware version. (2006!)  I also tried disabling "Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration"

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to connect to your VPS via Remote Desktop? If yes, then check the browser settings for Proxy and see how it connects to internet. If you are using FireFox then you need to follow below steps:

1. Open Firefox.
2. Click on Tools -> Options.
3. Go to Advanced -> Network tab.
4. Go to Connection -> Settings.

Comment: No proxy settings.  The other virtual machine works (its xp)  The one I'm having issue with is server 2003.  I created a new vm today with server 2003, and it still wont connect to the internet.

Comment: On further inspection I was incorrect, this answer was suitable.

Comment: and which actions we have to do after we pointed over "Settings" ?